# Adding extra table row

Tags: php, sql-server, html-table

I'm stuck and can't figure this out.

I have this piece of code which is basically generating a table taking data from SQL cursor.
I need to add one extra table row `<tr>` (which will be filled with additional info) after each row. I've tried putting the new row in several places, but there is never any output data for it.  This is someone else's code that I'm trying to modify.

```
  $top_i=min($pagesize-1,$numrows-$start);
  for($i = 0;$i<=$top_i;$i++) {
  if (($i%2)==1)
    echo "<tr class='saraksts_row0'>";

  else
    echo "<tr class='saraksts_row1'>";


  $res=mssql_query("fetch absolute ".($start+$i)." from saraksts_cursor ");
  $row=mssql_fetch_array($res);

  $itemp = 0;
  foreach($fields as $field) {
        $key = $field[0];
          if($field[2]) {
              eval($field[2] );
          }
          $itemp++;
          $val = ($row[$key] == "") ? "&nbsp;" : $row[$key];

          // Get rid of right and left border, set topmost border
          $st="";
          if ($itemp==1)
            $st.="border-left-style:none;";
          if ($itemp==$numfields)
            $st.="border-right-style:none;";
          if ($i==$top_i)
            $st.="border-bottom-style:solid;";

    echo "<td style='$st'>$val</td>";
  }
  $itemp = 0;

  echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: What, exactly, are you having problems with? Are there any error messages, if so what are they? You need to be more specific.

Comment: I cant figure out where to put <tr> </tr>. I tried to add <tr> in several locations but all the time there was no output data.

This is not my own code so I'm a bit confused

Comment: it needs to go at the bottom of the loop after you close your other row...fyi, your code sample seems to be missing the closing parenthesis for your `for` loop.  It should go between the end of your code sample and the closing parenthesis.

Comment: I updated the question with your comment and added the (missing) parenthesis at the end.  Please correct if I've got it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place where you want to add the extra row is after closing the first row and before the iteration moves to the next one.  Note, it appears that you are doing some styling based on whether the row is odd or even.  If you want this new row to have the same styling, I suggest you store the class you're applying to the preceding row so that you can also apply it to this row.

```
  echo "</tr>\n";
  echo "<tr><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>\n"; /* Add the new row here */
}
```

Comment: @user1109676 WTH? You accepted an answer that adds an extra column when your question asked for an extra row. Which is it?

Comment: I suspected to be an extra col from the OQs phrasing

Comment: @EugenRieck but in his comments on the question he specifically mentions `<tr></tr>`???

Comment: Sorry, I just guessed: I have worked on helpdesks for years and years trying to decode what a user really means

Comment: @EugenRieck - certainly understandable, but it leaves the question/answer pair as highly confusing to others.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117436/what-to-do-when-the-op-accepts-an-answer-that-actively-promotes-confusion

Comment: You are ofcourse right, I was simply trying to be helpfull. I guess the comments will clear the confuison up

Comment: @tvanfosson sorry! your answer was THE ONE. It was late evening and i made a mistake. thanks again for help

Answer (score 0):

```
...
            $st.="border-bottom-style:solid;";

    echo "<td style='$st'>$val</td>";
  }

  //Here we go
  echo '<td style="blah">'.$yourotherinfo.'</td>';


  $itemp = 0;

echo "</tr>\n";
```